# How get token from ember-simple-auth-token to use with Websocket?

Tags: ember.js, ember-simple-auth

In my implementation below I try get the token from `ember-simple-auth-token` and use with a URL, used to connect with ActionCable:

```
...

export default Route.extend({
  store: service(),
  currentUser: service(),
  session: service(),
  cable: service(),

  setupConsumer: on('init', function() {
    let token = this.get('session.data.authenticated.jwt');
    let consumer = this.get('cable')
      .createConsumer(`wss://api.${config.APP.host}/cable?token=${token}`);

    let channelMixin = Mixin.create({
      received(data) {
        this.get('store').pushPayload(data);
      }
    });

    consumer.subscriptions.create({
      channel: 'ChatroomsChannel'
    }, channelMixin);
  }),

  ...
});
```

This works only at first request. I need store this in a cookie? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The follow code solves my issue:

```
import Route from 'ember-route';
import service from 'ember-service/inject';
import Mixin from 'ember-metal/mixin';
import config from 'apollo-enterprise/config/environment';

export default Route.extend({
  session: service(),
  cable: service(),

  afterModel(model) {
    this.get('session.store').restore().then((data) => {
      let token = data.authenticated.jwt;
      let consumer = this.get('cable')
        .createConsumer(`wss://api.${config.APP.host}/cable?token=${token}`);

      let channelMixin = Mixin.create({
        store: service(),

        received(data) {
          this.get('store').pushPayload(data);
        }
      });

      consumer.subscriptions.create({
        channel: 'MessagesChannel',
        chatroom_id: model.id
      }, channelMixin);
    });
  },

  setupController(controller) {
    this._super(...arguments);

    controller.set('message', {});
  },

  actions: {
    sendMessage(params) {
      let chatroom = this.controller.get('model');
      let message = this.get('store').createRecord('message', params);

      message.set('chatroom', chatroom);
      message.save().then(() => {
        this.controller.set('message', {});
      });
    }
  }
});
```